# iphone in-app content payment process

Tags: iphone, payment, payment-processing

I'm planning to develop an app for a local magazine. The download would be for free, but inside the app, the user would be able to buy different numbers of the magazine.

Do I have to pay a comission to apple for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

And also: Read the appropriate guides:
[In App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Note that there have been recent (early February 2011) changes to how Apple interprets and enforces the policy.  For example, the Kindle and Nook apps used to be allowed to let users purchase books outside of the app for use within the app, but Apple is apparently going to stop allowing this.  So the answer may be unclear for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Google around and you should be able to find an answer.

http://www.iphonedownloadblog.com/2011/02/03/apple-clamping-down-on-in-app-purchases/